# Prove that $\text{dim}(W\cap V^{\perp})=1$ (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$, $W$ vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that: $$V\leq W\hspace{1cm}\textrm{and}\hspace{1cm}\textrm{dim }W=1+\textrm{dim }V.$$
How can i prove that:$$\textrm{dim }(W\cap V^{\perp})=1.$$Where $V^{\perp}=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \langle x,v \rangle=0\hspace{0.5cm}\textrm{for all }v \in V\}$, and $\langle x,v \rangle$ is the usual inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $m=\dim V$, and choose an orthonormal basis $w_1,\dots,w_m,w_{m+1}$ for $W$ such that $w_1,\dots,w_m$ is a basis for $V$. Then, as $\langle w_i,w_{m+1} \rangle = 0$ for $i=1,\dots,m$, we see that $w_{m+1} \in V^\perp$. On the other hand, if $w \in W \cap V^\perp$, write $w = a_1w_1 + \cdots + a_mw_m + a_{m+1}w_{m+1}$ for some $a_1,\dots,a_m,a_{m+1} \in \mathbb R$, and then note that, for $j=1,\dots,m$, $$0 = \langle w,w_j \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{m+1} a_i \langle w_i,w_j \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i \delta_{ij} = a_j$$ so $w = a_{m+1}w_{m+1}$.